# Unable to successfully sign Mac Catalyst app with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, mac-catalyst

I've been trying to solve this problem off and on for multiple weeks now to no avail. I even have a DTS open with Apple but so far they haven't been able to help me.

Essentially, I am creating a Mac Catalyst version of an existing iOS app, and I want to use the same bundle ID to have the in-app purchases be cross-platform (now that that's a thing).

I can build and run locally without issue, and it archives just fine. However, there's some sort of signing issue that prevents it from uploading successfully. I have tried both automatic and manual signing.

I get the following error when trying to upload:

> App Store Connect Operation Error: ERROR ITMS-90283: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle org.cocoapods.gRPCCertificates-Cpp [.pkg/Payload/.app/Contents/Resources/gRPCCertificates-Cpp.bundle] is invalid. [Invalid 'com.apple.application-identifier' entitlement value.] For more information, visit the macOS Developer Portal.

The initial advice was to not sign the gRPCCertificates-Cpp bundle, which does not help.

It's also strange that I have another catalyst app that uses the same bundle and it works just fine, so I think it's less an issue with that bundle and more how Xcode handles entitlements and signing. Though I'm open to all suggestions.

One possible difference between the app that works fine and the problematic one is that the problematic one uses an explicit App ID Prefix and the other has a Team ID prefix.

Another potential clue, I need to enabled *Associated Domains*, *Autofill Credential Provider*, *Sign In with Apple* and *iCloud Key Value Storage* entitlements for my app to function correctly. However, if I remove all of those and retain only *In-App Purchase*, *Hardened Runtime*, and *App Sandbox* entitlements the app **does** sign and upload successfully to the App Store.

So I'm thinking the issue must have something to do with these entitlements or how Xcode handles them compared to the others.

Does anyone have any ideas on what else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

As of July 8 2020, this issue has been fixed by Apple.

Comment: I would not say, still getting this issue and I'm not able to send Mac Catalyst build to AppStore because of gRPCCertificates-Cpp signing :(

Comment: @goodliving Have you tried removing the Code Signing Identity from gRPCCertificates-Cpp bundle (Other... -> leave blank)?